# How can I move some product with Agent Truck from a manufacturer to Warehouse on GIS until a capacity of the product is reached

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a product (flower vase) of about 200,000 at Agent manufacturer to be moved to 4 different warehouses with the different number of the requested vase. The truck to move this vase will have a parameter "capacity" so that I can dynamically set this capacity at a model run time, which will determine the number of times the truck can move to and fro until the requested vase at each warehouse is completed. Once completed, the truck would stop at the manufacturer.

I need logic to go about this... any assistance would be helpful as I am new to anylogic

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. For general, non-tech questions like this, best use the LinkedIn forum. See this guide: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community

Comment: The best option is to get your hands dirty and start modeling. Once you run into a real technical problem raise it here if you are completely new to AnyLogic you need to start with some tutorials and example models - see here https://www.anylogic.com/getting-started/